# How can I convert my gwt app thats hosted on app-engine into a installable mobile app?

Tags: java, iphone, google-app-engine, gwt, html5-appcache

Currently my app is created in Eclipse using GWT and Coded in Java. I have the app hosted on app-engine and all my data is saved in the browser using html5 storage.  I want to have this app installable on an iPhone so I included  "\<\meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />\ " in my html file, and even included a custom icon etc for the iPhone.

Upon installing the app on my iPhone, everything works fine online but offline the app won't even load. I've been reading about manifests and yaml's but I cant get a clear picture of how to set my app up mobile, and have it save data locally on the phone (app cache).

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to start reading about HTML offline apps for iPhone. There are a lot of resources about this on the net, for example [this](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/) and [this](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/chapOfflineApplicationCache.html).

Comment: You see this is the issue im having. All these tutorials all talk about java script in the manifest file. I have a java gwt app that is hosted on google app-engine. I need a way to put the manifest on google app-engine to be served to the offline app. I cannot find a way to do this, and with the java i put the java class in the manifest file along with the css and all the files that the offline app will need is that correct, or does java not apply in a manifest file?

Comment: <mime-mapping>
       <extension>appcache</extension>
       <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>         - adding this into my web.xml serves the manifest file as cache-manifest to app-engine. Also using manifestR will help you construct your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

mgwt - mobile GWT has a HTML5 Manifest Linker, see: http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/HTML5Manifest

This can be easily used to store your app locally.

Also stake a look at the mgwt settings class: http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/MGWTSettings.java

There you can find all the properties described in the tutorials Peter Knego described.

Comment: Im not sure how to set mime type in gwt for the manifest file to be served as text/cache-manifest, but modifying the script type in the html worked i guess? I added the servlet to serve up the manifest file but upon compilation it tells me it cant find my java class i tried the relative path and everything, so I copy and pasted my java class into my war and then it recognized it. I then deployed it to app engine and on my iphone i installed the app. After installation it will only run once. Upon running it again it just puts up a white screen.